# TypeScript Compiler API: get type structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Is there an API method to get the "bottomed out" type information from the TypeScript compiler? Example:

```
interface User {
  id: number
  name: string
}

type NameOnly = Pick<User, 'name'>

type NameOnlyAliased = NameOnly
```

In VSCode, if I hover over `NameOnlyAliased`, it shows:

```
type NameOnlyAliased = {
    name: string;
}
```

My question is if there is a function in the compiler API (or other simple way without applying the semantics of aliases, `Pick`, etc.) to get the info on the right-hand side of the `=` above, preferably as data (not just a string), something like:

```
{
  NameAliasedOnly: {
    properties: {
      name: {
         type: 'string'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The use-case is to generate code to create `fast-check` arbitraries from type definitions (if that already exists, then fantastic). I've played around a bit with using `ts-json-schema-generator` for this purpose, but there are some type definitions it doesn't handle.

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? It may be that someone could provide an answer that doesn't answer your exact question, but does solve your problem. What I mean by that is, maybe there's a way to do whatever you need to do, but it just can't be done with this exact approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a solution. It doesn't use the TypeScript compiler API, directly, but rather the excellent [ts-morph library](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/tree/latest/packages/ts-morph), a wrapper for the compiler API which simplifies many tasks. Here's some example code, where the `test.ts` file contains the example code from my question above.

```
import { Project, TypeFormatFlags } from 'ts-morph'

const project = new Project({
  tsConfigFilePath: 'tsconfig.json',
  skipAddingFilesFromTsConfig: true,
})
const file = 'test.ts'
project.addSourceFileAtPath(file)

const sourceFile = project.getSourceFile(file)

const typeAlias = sourceFile?.getTypeAlias('NameOnlyAliased')
if (typeAlias) {
  console.log(
    typeAlias
      .getType()
      .getProperties()
      .map(p => [
        p.getName(),
        p
          .getTypeAtLocation(typeAlias)
          .getText(
            undefined,
            TypeFormatFlags.UseAliasDefinedOutsideCurrentScope
          ),
      ])
  )
}
```

Executing this script gives output `[ [ 'name', 'string' ] ]`, as desired. For more complex types you can navigate into the type hierarchy.

Comment: I stumbled on basically the same solution, but I didn't catch the TypeFormatFlags bit.  Thanks for that.  That said, beware the union types.  If you call node.getType().getUnionTypes().length and get a positive number, you could be missing several properties.  (In my particular use case, generating a stub class from a type, union types are a Bad Thing.  But they might not be for yours.)

Answer (score 1):

I created a CLI tool, [ts-simplify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-simplify), based off of @sparkofreason's answer.
It's a compiler, which outputs the simplified primitive types.  For example:

```bash
npx ts-simplify source-code.ts output-types.ts
```

This would output a file with the desired output:

```
export type NameOnlyAliased = {
    name: string;
}
```