# Check if TypeScript (AST) types are equal programatically

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a tool that should indicate whether a TypeLiteral equals to given TypeNode. For example:

```js
// type ABC = { a: number; b: number; c: number; };
const typeABC: ts.TypeAliasDeclaratio = ...;
isEqual(typeABC, "{a: number; b: number; c: number; }") // true

// Pick<ABC, "a" | "b">;
const typeAB: ts.TypeReferenceNode = ...;
isEqual(typeAB, "{ a: number; b: number; }") // true


// type BC = { b: number; } & { c: number; };
const typeBC: ts.IntersectionTypeNode = ...;
isEqual(typeBC, "{ b: number; c: number }"); // true
```

I thought about using `ts.createPrinter` and then comparing the strings, but it would just print the type implementation rather than a flattened type (`type Flatten<T> = T extends {} ? { [k in keyof T]: T[k] } : T;`).

Since TypeScript playground won't be enough, [I created a StackBlitz reproduction instead](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-pg413x?file=index.ts)

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531850/typescript-compiler-api-get-type-structure

Comment: By the way, your example kinda doesn't make sense... your stackblitz says AB and BC should be equal? They shouldn't be, right? One has a/b and the other has b/c.

Comment: @caTS Sadly I can't use ts-morph (only typescript). Plus, I believe the example solves only basic cases. Thanks for pointing out the issue with the example. I have updated the link!

Comment: Another related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44889930/18244921 - I tried tinkering in the stackblitz myself but I couldn't find anything that could do this.